# How do you pull up relationship created date of entity framework relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How do you pull up date of entity framework relationship mapping table save date. e.g Movie and Type tables, when creating many to many relationship, MovieTypes table is created. How do you retrieve the date when this relationship was created by entity framework.

```
public class Movie
{
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Type> Types { get; set; }
}


public class Type
{
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public string MovieType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```